# Rails model.create set id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wonder if it's possible to to run `Model.create()` such that instead of taking next free `id` integer it takes the lowest free integer.

For example, assume we have records for `id=10..20` and we don't have records for `id=0..9`, I want create instance of Model with `id` starting from 0 (in normal Mode.create() in would create instance staring from 21)

Preferably I want to do it in automatic manner. I don't want to change `id` by explicitly defining it.

Comment: What is the reason you want to use this functionality? Rails do not associate id to the model instead the database provides value for the autoincrement id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DB**

You'll be best doing this at database-level (look at altering the [`auto-increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) number)

Although I think you can do this in Rails, I would highly recommend using the DB functionality to make it happen. You can do something like this in PHPMYAdmin (for MYSQL):

[image]

If you set the Auto-Increment to the number you wish to start at, every time you save data into the DB, it will just save with that number. I think using any Rails-based method will just overcomplicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: in postgres you can achieve this by `ALTER SEQUENCE models_id_seq RESTART WITH 1453;` if your sequence `models_id_seq`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd discourage it.

Those `id`s serve solely as unique identifiers  for rows in a table, and it's the database's job to assign one. You can verify that the model doesn't require an `id` to be saved:

```
m = Model.new
# populate m with data
m.name = "Name"
# look at what m contains
m
# and save it
m.save
# now inspect it again and see it got its unique id
m
```

While it might be possible to modify `id`s, it's not a good practice to give more sense to `id`s — when each new record gets a **unique** `id` **at any time** it's easier to debug possible DB structure errors that might occur during development. Like, say, some associated objects suddenly show up in a new user's account. Weird enough, right? That can happen and, worst case, can show up in production resulting in a severe security breach.

Keeping `id`s unique at all times eliminates this bug's effect. That seems much more important if the associated objects store **confidential information** and you care about keeping them safe. Encryption concerns aside.

So, to be sure in every situation, developers have adopted a practice of not giving `id` any other role other than uniquely identifying a row in a table. If you want it to do something else, consider making another field for that purpose.